# DataFrame in python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, save, element

I make DataFrame in python and there is a array for example (3*600) in last column for each raw.
I save this DataFrame but when I read that it can't read all elements of array and make them short.
1.what can I do to save and read all them?

Comment: How do you save your dataframe? What datatype is this last column?

Comment: Please add a minimal example of your data to help us understand the problem.

Comment: Include the code that you have tried and the structure of the dataframe.